# How to define a function that will check any data frame for Age column and return bins?

Tags: python, dataframe, binning, bins

I am trying to define a function that will take any dataframe with an 'Age' column, bin the ages, and return how many Xs are in each age category.

Consider the following:

```
def age_range():
        x = input("Enter Dataframe Name: ")
        df = x
        df['Age']
        bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
        labels=['0-9', '10-19', '20s', '30s', '40s', '50s', '60s', '70s', '80s', '90s','100s']
        pd.df['AgeGroup'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
        return print("Age Ranges:", result)
```

I keep getting a Type Error: string indices must be integers.

I thought that by calling the df['Age'], it would return a one-column series from which the binning and labelling would work effectively. But it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lies here

```
x = input("Enter Dataframe Name: ") # type of x is a string
df = x # now type of df is also a string
df['Age'] # python uses [] as a slicing operation for string, hence generate error
```

this would resolve your problem

```
def age_range(df):
        bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
        labels=['0-9', '10-19', '20s', '30s', '40s', '50s', '60s', '70s', '80s', '90s']
        result = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
        return result
```

for example, you can run it like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : [random.randint(1, 99) for i in range(500)]})
df["AgeRange"] = age_range(df)
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : [random.randint(1, 99) for i in range(500)]})
AgeRangeDf = pd.DataFrame({"Age_Range" :age_range(df)})
```

Comment: This is very helpful! How do I get this into a single column data frame then?

Comment: one of the way is 
df = pd.DataFrame({"AgeRanges" : list(result)})
but I would suggest keep it like this 
df["AgeRange"] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)

Please upvote the answer if it helped.

Comment: That's giving me an NoneType Object. It won't let me make that into a df.

Comment: yeah my bad, print is of None type, updating the code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the total bin counts over the dataFrame:

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : [random.randint(1, 99) for i in range(100)]})

def age_range(df):
    import pandas as pd
    df['Age']
    bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
    labels=['0-9', '10-19', '20s', '30s', '40s', '50s', '60s', '70s', '80s', '90s']
    df['AgeGroup'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)

    result = pd.DataFrame(df['AgeGroup'].groupby(df['AgeGroup']).count())
    return result
print(age_range(df1))
```

This returns a single column DataFrame

Comment: How do I include those which don't have a recorded age: NAN?

Comment: That would depend on what you want NAN to be categorized as, but this should do the trick.
    result = pd.DataFrame(df['AgeGroup'].groupby(df['AgeGroup']).count()).fillna(0).
you can update NAN values using Pandas DataFrame.fillna() method